# Vue - how to correctly loop array of subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, loops, electron

I have this code in a vue component of my electron app.

```js
        paginateDatasets() {
            // Splitto array fornitori per impaginazione
            for( let i = 0; i < this.store.suppliers.length; i = i + this.paginationLength ){
                this.suppliersDataset.push( this.store.suppliers.slice(i, i+this.paginationLength) )
            }
            // Splitto array clienti per impaginazione
            for( let i = 0; i < this.store.clients.length; i = i + this.clientsDataset ){
                this.clientsDataset.push( this.store.clients.slice(i, i+this.paginationLength) )
            }           
        }
```

I have defined a store where I have the two arrays `suppliers` and `clients`, these two arrays are filled with some data that are taken from an odbc MS Access db. the suppliers array is correctly splitted into 40 sub arrays, the clients seems that will be not splitted, it's always equal to the original one of 58000 entry. Anyway, my problem is another, how I can correctly loop the splitted arrays into my vue js template?

I'm using at the moment this code and I will need to modify the loop I think?

```html
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" v-if="!store.supplierFound && suppliersLoaded">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="( result, i ) in store.suppliers" :key="i" ref="listedSupplier" :data-index="i">
                <div class="row m-0">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-dark" @click.prevent="addResultToDocumentsList('supplier', result)">
                            <i class="bi bi-plus-lg fs-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase">1</label>
                        <p class="text-uppercase">
                            {{ result.CFOR }}
                        </p>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase">2</label>
                        <p class="text-uppercase">
                            {{ result.XFOR }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase">3</label>
                        <p class="text-uppercase">
                            {{ result.NEMA }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thank you for the help